# Laravel Forgot Password (Reset Password)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel app, and the password reset feature is needed. How can I flash a session message after the email is sent to the user or after clicking the submit button?

I can't seem to add a flash method to the function that returns the view of the reset password page, because the file is in the vendor folder.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passwords

Comment: What I actually mean is, I can't seem to add a flash method to the function that returns the view of the reset password page, because the file is in the vendor folder.

Comment: You should edit your question with that important detail instead of leaving it in the comments which tend to get overlooked.  It would also help to see some code from what you have tried so far.  Please read the help section on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Added your comment to the question. You can edit your question to make it more clear - this will help you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After an hour of tracing of what function will be triggered after the submission of the password reset form, I have found out that:

- After submission of the password reset form, the function sendResetLinkEmail will be triggered, can be found in SendsPasswordResetEmails.php.
- Then in line 37

  `return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                  ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                  : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);`
- The sendResetLinkResponse function is the one responsible for what happens if the email is sent successfully.

`protected function sendResetLinkResponse($response)
    {
        return back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }`

By default, laravel auth:make doesn't display the 'status' variable in the front end or the reset password page.

I have to add these lines of code to the reset password template.

`@if(session()->has('status'))
                <div class="alert-container">
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        {{ Session::get('status') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endif`

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#flash-data):

> Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the `flash` method. Data stored in the session using this method will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, and then will be deleted. Flash data is primarily useful for short-lived status messages:

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

Comment: I am aware of that method. What I actually mean is, I can't seem to add a flash method to the function that returns the view of the reset password page, because the file is in the vendor folder.

Comment: @Lucentyr in this case you need to override it in a controller you're using and add the code I've shown.

Comment: will try. Thanks.